# Perl LibXML raw data from textContent?

Tags: perl, libxml2

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Request>
    <form_submit>
        <form_submit id = 1424>
            <form_id>1424</form_id>
            <field1 id=’5’> <![CDATA[ test   ]]>   </field1>
            <field2 id=’6’> <![CDATA[ test2   ]]>   </field2>
        </form_submit>
    </form_submit>
</Request>
```

I'm trying to get the raw values for the field1 and field2 elements. I'm using the following code:

```
foreach my $node ( $xml_request->findnodes('Request/*/*/*[@id]') )
{
    my $form_field_value = $node->textContent;
    print "Value:\"$form_field_value\"\n";
}
```

But the output is:

```
Value:" test   "
Value:" test2  "
```

How do I retrieve the exact data, raw and as is, with all the special characters? So that the output is:

```
Value:" <![CDATA[ test   ]]>   "
Value:" <![CDATA[ test2   ]]>   "
```

Thank you.

Comment: What if the XML of the text is `&lt;foo&gt;`?

Comment: fyi, your request reeks of bad design.

Answer (score 2):

Am not a libxml expert. 
However this is what I could figure out after playing with your xml and libxml a bit.
CDATA is a node/section and is not part of text.
Code below goes one level deep and do a toString() for cdata child nodes 
and textContent for other nodes.

```
foreach my $node ( $xml_request->findnodes('Request/*/*/*[@id]') )
{
    my $text;
    if($node->childNodes) {
        foreach my $child ($node->childNodes()) {
            if ($child->nodeType == XML::LibXML::XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
                $text .= $child->toString;
            } else {
                $text .= $child->textContent;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $text = $node->textContent;
    }
    print qq{"$text"\n};
}
```

will print

```
" <![CDATA[ test   ]]>   "
" <![CDATA[ test2   ]]>   "
```

Comment: `$child->nodeName eq "cdata"` didn't work for me. I need `$child->nodeName eq "#cdata-section"`. I switched your code to something more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample data is invalid XML, and won't parse unless you replace `1424`, `’5’` and `’6’` with `"1424"`, `"5"` and `"6"`.

You have asked for the text content and have got exactly that. To get what you need you must search for the *children* of the `<fieldN>` elements and use the `toString` method on them.

This code shows the idea. Note that the spaces before and after the `CDATA`, which would otherwise appear as separate text nodes, have been eliminated using a `keep_blanks => 0` option on the object constructor.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_request = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'END', keep_blanks => 0);
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Request>
  <form_submit>
    <form_submit id = "1424">
      <form_id>1424</form_id>
      <field1 id="5"> <![CDATA[ test   ]]>   </field1>
      <field2 id="6"> <![CDATA[ test2   ]]>   </field2>
    </form_submit>
  </form_submit>
</Request>
END

foreach my $node ( $xml_request->findnodes('//form_submit/*[@id]/text()') ) {
  my $form_field_value = $node->toString;
  print qq(Value: "$form_field_value"\n);
}
```

**output**

```
Value: "<![CDATA[ test   ]]>"
Value: "<![CDATA[ test2   ]]>"
```

---

**Edit**

[ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) has commented that the output requested in the question includes the whitespace surrounding the CDATA section. I don't know whether that is truly part of the requirement, but this edit provides a way to do that.

This would be clearer using [`XML::LibXML::Reader`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::Reader) as it has a `readInnerXml` method (comparable to JavaScript's `innerHTML` ) that does exactly what is necessary. Instead, this program has to serialize all the children of the `<fieldN>` nodes and concatenate them with `join`.

This is a new `foreach` loop. The rest of the program remains unchanged except for the construction of `$xml_request`, which must have the `keep_blanks` option set to `1` or removed altogether.

```perl
foreach my $node ( $xml_request->findnodes('//*[starts-with(name(),"field")][@id]') ) {
  my $form_field_value = join '', map $_->toString, $node->childNodes;
  print qq(Value: "$form_field_value"\n);
}
```

**output**

```
Value: " <![CDATA[ test   ]]>   "
Value: " <![CDATA[ test2   ]]>   "
```

Comment: He wanted the surrounding spaces too.

Comment: @ikegami: *apostrophes* - `"\x27"` - are allowed. The characters in the question are Unicode U+2019 - `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` - which aren't valid. Please raise a comment instead of editing my answers.

Comment: @Namuna: is the whitespace surrounding the CDATA section significant or is this solution satisfactory as it is?